# accessing the activeIndex

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm VERY new to react, JS and coding in general and after reading through the documentation a few times I still can't figure this out. I'm using the swiper.js package with react. Initial setup is working fine, but now I am trying to access the activeIndex and can't figure out how to get it. If anyone can help me to access that would be great, thanks!

```
    import React from 'react';
    import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, } from 'swiper';
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
    import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
    import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss';
    import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss';

    export default class SlideShow extends React.Component {

        render() {

          SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination,]);

            return (
              <Swiper
              spaceBetween={10}
              slidesPerView={1}
              navigation
              pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            >
              <SwiperSlide><img alt={"alt text here"} src={image1}/></SwiperSlide>
              <SwiperSlide><img alt={"alt text here"} src={image2}/></SwiperSlide>
              <SwiperSlide><img alt={"alt text here"} src={image3}/></SwiperSlide>
    
            </Swiper>
            );
       }
   }
```

Comment: Where is the `activeIndex` you are attempting to access? I see none in your shared code snippet. Are there any error messages, etc? You probably don't want to use `SwiperCore.use` in the component, seems it should be called once to install the swiper components.

Comment: @DrewReese activeIndex is listed in the documentation as a property that offers the index of the currently active slide.. it's listed here, under slider methods & properties... I just can't figure out how to implement as a newb. https://swiperjs.com/api/#parameters .Good call on SwiperCore.use I'll fix that.

Comment: If you are referring to `mySwiper.activeIndex` this appears to be specific to an instance of a [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/#initialize) object. I don't see anything related to an "activeIndex" when looking at the [react docs](https://swiperjs.com/react/) other than when you use the `SwiperSlide` render function.

Comment: @DrewReese yes that's what I am referring to, sorry I'm a total beginner... I'm basically just trying to figure out a way to know what image is currently visible... if you have any ideas that would be great. thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, was able to log via onSlideChange event:  onSlideChange={(swiper) => console.log(swiper.activeIndex)} Thanks for the assistance nonetheless.